# MathJax menu obliterates link menu when the entire link is LaTeX

Tags: bug, status-deferred, mathjax

When the title of a link is entirely in LaTeX, e.g. a question named on the front page such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11567/gcdbx-1-by-1-b-z-1-b-gcdx-y-z-1), then there is no way to get the link menu (e.g. to copy the url) since the MathJaX menu applies to the whole link.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: @KennyTM: I can confirm this on Firefox 3.6. I suggest the workaround that question titles simply shouldn't be entirely in TeX.

Comment: @Rahul: Yes, one could force some link "stub" into the title upon which one could click. That's one common workaround for problems of this nature.

Comment: It's not really even a workaround. A properly written title should be in the form of a grammatically complete question, so you shouldn't have all TeX titles in the first place. For example, the linked question ought to be "How can we prove that $\gcd(b^x - 1, b^y - 1, b^ z- 1,…) = b^{\gcd(x, y, z,…)} -1$?".

Comment: The same problem exists with Google Chrome.

Comment: See my [comment to a similar post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/8911/7798) for a possible work-around.

Answer (score 4):

In any case, even if you can't click on the title, you should be able to copy the standard link from the footer menu of the question as well.

[image]

Comment: That doesn't work for the question page - see my comment to Kenny's answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'll mark this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). As long as we support LaTeX in title (which is widely used) and MathJax's context menu, we can't avoid this.

In Firefox, you could [turn off "Disable or replace context menus"](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Javascript#Advanced_JavaScript_settings). Then *both* menus will appear.

Comment: Please read my post more carefully since nothing you wrote abve applies to it. The point is that you can't copy the url from the link on the list of questions since the only menu there is the MathJax menu. Of course I know how to copy a url from the address bar or right-clicking (when available). But I should not have to visit the page first to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the FireFox tip, but I often use a variety of browsers and not all have such capabilities afaik. In any case that's really a kludge. It should be fixed correctly.

Comment: Is there way to do something similar with Google Chrome?